# Serenity + Maven Failsafe ignores tests and adds @Manual tag on them

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, maven-failsafe-plugin, cucumber-serenity

So basically my problem is Serenity with Cucumber sometimes 'ignores' results of tests. Tests seem to be executed on the report, but still result is ignored. Also, on the report, it shows @Manual tag is added, but it is not added in the feature file.
There is a random number of these tests for each regression, sometimes 2, sometimes 30, and I cannot figure out why that happens. Seems like nobody had the same problem before since I had problems finding topics about this. :$

[Manual tag added, but in feature file there is no @Manual tag.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq1BJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the @manual tag, probably a bug in the framework. It is fixed by adding 'and not @manual' when executing tests.